# XSLT if node has attribute value, put it in sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt

I've recently "discovered" XSLT and am probably overusing it in my current project, but having alot of fun with it and that's what counts.

In my example, I have some HTML code that looks like this:

```
<table>
          <tr class="itemRow">
            <td class="hide">MAIN001</td>
            <td class="orderBoxQty ">1</td>
            <td class="orderBoxItem itemCell">Burger</td>
            <td class="orderBoxTotalPrice ">15.00</td>
            <td class="orderBoxCourse ">Mains</td>
            <td class="hide">15.00</td>
            <td class="hide">2</td>
            <td class="hide">item</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="instructionRow">
            <td class="hide">INSTRUCTION002</td>
            <td class="orderBoxQty invisibleText">1</td>
            <td class="orderBoxItem itemCell">Add Bacon</td>
            <td class="orderBoxTotalPrice ">1.50</td>
            <td class="orderBoxCourse invisibleText">3</td>
            <td class="hide">1.50</td>
            <td class="hide">3</td>
            <td class="hide">instruction</td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

Which I want to transform to clean XML, which I am doing with an existing XSL transform, so the output looks something like this:

```
   <item type="item">
      <id>MAIN001</id>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <name>Burger</name>
      <unitprice>15.00</unitprice>
      <totalprice>15.00</totalprice>
      <printgroup>Mains</printgroup>
   </item>
   <item type="instruction">
      <id>INSTRUCTION002</id>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <name>Add Bacon</name>
      <unitprice>1.50</unitprice>
      <totalprice>1.50</totalprice>
      <printgroup>3</printgroup>
   </item>
```

I'm achieving that by a foreach of each `<tr>` and then assigning the type attribute based on the class.

Now I want to be a bit more ambitious. If the HTML has class="instructionRow", I want to embed it in the previous  tag, so it would like this:

```
   <item type="item">
      <id>MAIN001</id>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <name>Burger</name>
      <unitprice>15.00</unitprice>
      <totalprice>15.00</totalprice>
      <printgroup>Mains</printgroup>
     <!--if there's an instruction row next, it goes here-->      
     <instruction>
          <id>INSTRUCTION002</id>
          <name>Add Bacon</name>
          <unitprice>1.50</unitprice>
      </instruction>
   </item>
```

There are no case where an instruction row would ever be present without a preceding item row, and it's no huge deal to manipulate this with programming, but am wondering what I should be looking at for a pure XSLT solution.

The current data and XSLT is here: http://xsltransform.net/gVTZeVo/2

I am testing  `test="following-sibling::tr/@class = 'instructionRow'"`
in an if statement, but that checks all siblings with class instructionRow, I only want it to select siblings with instructionRow UNTIL it gets to sibling that doesn't (or runs out of siblings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <!-- root - kick things off -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <order>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='table/tbody/tr[@class = "itemRow"]' mode='item'/>
        </order>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- iteration item - item -->
    <xsl:template match='tr' mode='item'>
        <item type="item">
            <id><xsl:value-of select="td[1]" /></id>
            <quantity><xsl:value-of select="td[2]" /></quantity>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="td[3]" /> </name>
            <unitprice><xsl:value-of select="td[6]" /> </unitprice>
            <totalprice><xsl:value-of select="td[4]" /> </totalprice>
            <printgroup><xsl:value-of select="td[5]" /></printgroup>      
            <xsl:apply-templates select='following-sibling::tr[@class = "instructionRow" and preceding-sibling::tr[@class = "itemRow"][1] = current()]' mode='instruction'/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- iteration item - instruction -->
    <xsl:template match='tr' mode='instruction'>
        <instruction>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="td[1]" /></id>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="td[3]" /> </name>
            <unitprice><xsl:value-of select="td[6]" /> </unitprice>
        </instruction>
    </xsl:template>
```

Note I've ditched the `for-each` - these are *normally* best avoided in XSLT in favour of using templates instead.

The logic here is to have a template for each item type (since both match `tr`, we distinguish between them with the `mode` identifier attribute).

After transforming an item row, we check its next sibling (only) and, if it's an instruction row, output that - within the current iteration item.

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit of an adjusment to thinking, the foreach is very easy to understand coming form programming!

At first test, this doesn't quite work how I want it to - ```<xsl:apply-templates select='following-sibling::tr[1][@class = "instructionRow"]' mode='instruction'/>``` only transforms the first instructionRow following a normal itemRow. Whereas I want all instructionRows inside the preceding itemRow. I might be able to get this myself playing around but don't think it's gonna be quick!

Comment: All instruction rows *anywhere* should be in the preceding item row, or...?

Comment: And you can think of the `apply-templates` alternative to `for-each` as basically another form of `for-each`, but it has benefits.

Comment: All instruction rows between item rows should be in the preceding item row. So it could be an itemRow followed by 6 instruction rows, then another item row (or end of document)
Am trying to get my head arround the " Kayessian" method which might be the right direction.

Comment: See edit - try now. Now we get all the proceding instruction row until the next item row (or run out of items).

Comment: This is starting to look like a grouping question, which means we need to know which version of XSLT you are using: complex queries like this become much easier in XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. (If you're aiming to have fun, and why not, then you definitely want to be using the latest version!)